Proxmox Setup with Email Server and multiple Webservers - Need Help, can not send Emails from Webserver VMs
I run a Proxmox server that runs an email server and several web servers as VMs. The server has two external IP addresses configured to the Proxmox host via the /etc/network/interfaces file. The second incoming IP is currently configured as an alias of the first incoming IP.
The email ports 143, 993, 587, 465, 110, 995 and 25 are forwarded to the email server with the internal IP 10.10.10.200 using IPTables. However, with this setup I have the problem that my other web servers can no longer send emails. I suspect this is related to the port forwarding of the email ports.
Unfortunately, I don't know enough about configuring /etc/network/interfaces and IPTables. Can you help me solve this problem?
Is there perhaps an option to create a separate interface for the second incoming IP so that it is not configured as an alias of the first IP?
Many thanks for your help!
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 100.100.100.42/24 # Example first incoming IP
    gateway 100.100.100.1
    bridge-ports enp2s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address  10.10.10.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

    post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

    # Mailserver
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:143
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:143
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:993
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:993
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:587
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:587
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:465
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:465
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 110 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:110
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 110 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:110
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:995
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:995
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:25
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.200:25

    # Nameserver
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53

    # Rescue Bind-Control
    # post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 5010 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:80
    # post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 5010 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:80

iface vmbr0:0 inet static
    address 100.100.101.42/24 # Example secound incoming IP
    gateway 100.100.101.1
    bridge-ports enp2s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0

Many thanks for help.
If the Proxmox firewall is useless, so can I delete or comment out this 5 lines:
post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

Here is the result of iptables-save on the root machine:
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Mon May 20 13:18:11 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [139:119051]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [14:2209]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [129:136580]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A f2b-sshd -s 37.225.30.230/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 61.177.172.136/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 185.196.9.162/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 61.177.172.160/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 180.101.88.221/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 218.92.0.34/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 180.101.88.196/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -s 193.32.162.29/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 20 13:18:11 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Mon May 20 13:18:11 2024
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2748395:2113029968]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2015616:2356826919]
-A PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 20 13:18:11 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Mon May 20 13:18:11 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [203363:14376774]
:INPUT ACCEPT [95824:5642818]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18466:1161178]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [70901:5384040]
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:143
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:993
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:587
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:465
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:110
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:995
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:25
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:53
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:53
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 20 13:18:11 2024


web servers can no longer send emails — so what happens when they try? Also, irrespective of that, why wouldn't you make them send mail through your mail server (that would be very obvious thing to do)?

Thank you very much for the answer.
For sending Email from Webservers im using PHP Mailer to send the mails over the Mailsserver but I dont can connect from my Webserver to my Mailserver by the Email Ports.
Thing its block by my wrong IPTables Setup.

First of all, I see you mix Proxmox's firewall with ad-hoc iptables rules (fwbr is the sign of enabled Proxmox firewall for a VM). Are you actually using it (having any rules)? If no, it doesn't make sense to have it enabled, since it permits everything by default, but makes debugging way harder (e.g. 4 virtual interfaces are created in the host for each virtual NIC, with non-trivial routing). And, if you do using it, why making these ad-hoc rules? // Then, I see nothing in your firewall ever blocking any traffic. Export your actual live firewall with iptables-save for us to see.

So ok, are you trying to connect from web servers to your mail server using its public ip, or using its private ip 10.10.10.200? The former won't work (because their traffic won't be going in via vmbr0, therefore won't get matched and DNATed, so it won't reach the VM) while the latter should.

Sorry, that answer is to large for an comment :-(
I have tried both connect over the internal IP and over external.
If I renove the rule for port 25 I can connect by the internal IP.

Not a comment, you'd have to edit the question and add that info, as if it was there from the start. And remove non-answer. The "your answer" box is only for answers (that suggest what to do to solve the problem), not for anything else.
